# How to show user suspended reason?

Tags: php, session

I have a Pay To Click script and in this script we have a option to suspend member and when that member try to login his account with their username and password and click on login button instantly our system show him a error: "Your Account is Suspended".

But I want to show the suspended reason to every user. I mean when I suspend any user, I will write a reason why he is suspended and after that when that user try to login his account our system will show him a error (your account is suspended) and then line break and there I want to show him the reason.

I have already created a column in Member's table with name "susreason" and also I have shown it to my admin panel to every user edit option with suspend option. Now when I suspend a user and write the reason of suspension then user suspended successfully but the system did not show the reason because user session not logged in.

Below is the code, this is in my login.php:

```
$username = $db->real_escape_string($input->pc['username']);
    $password = $input->p['password'];
    $country = ip2country($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $ip_user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sect = explode(".", $ip_user);
    $reip = ((($sect[0] . ".") . $sect[1] . ".") . $sect[2] . ".") . $sect[3];
    $reipa = (($sect[0] . ".") . $sect[1] . ".") . $sect[2] . ".*";
    $reipb = ($sect[0] . ".") . $sect[1] . ".*.*";
    $reipc = $sect[0] . ".*.*.*";
    $verifyusername = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM blacklist WHERE type='username' AND criteria='" . $username . "'"));
    $ipban1 = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM blacklist WHERE type='ip' AND criteria='" . $reip . "'"));
    $ipban2 = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM blacklist WHERE type='ip' AND criteria='" . $reipa . "'"));
    $ipban3 = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM blacklist WHERE type='ip' AND criteria='" . $reipb . "'"));
    $ipban4 = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM blacklist WHERE type='ip' AND criteria='" . $reipc . "'"));
    $countryban = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM blacklist WHERE type='country' AND criteria='" . $country . "'"));

    if ($verifyusername != 0) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['usernameblocked']);
    }
    else {
        if ((($ipban1 != 0 || $ipban2 != 0) || $ipban3 != 0) || $ipban4 != 0) {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['ipblocked']);
        }
        else {
            if ($countryban != 0) {
                serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['countryblocked']);
            }
        }
    }

    $verifyuser = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE username='" . $username . "'"));

    if ($verifyuser == 0) {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidlogindetails']);
    }

    $user_info = $db->fetchRow(("SELECT id, username, password, status, country FROM members WHERE username='" . $username . "'"));

    if ($user_info['password'] != md5($password)) {
        $bid = array("user_id" => $user_info['id'], "ip" => $ip_user, "status" => "Failed", "password" => $password, "date" => TIMENOW, "agent" => (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : $_ENV['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
        $upd = $db->insert("login_history", $bid);
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['invalidlogindetails']);
    }


    if ($settings['multi_login'] == "yes") {
        $checkip = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE last_ip='" . $ip_user . "' AND id!=" . $user_info['id']);

        if ($checkip != 0) {
            $showip_error = "yes";
        }


        if ($showip_error == "yes") {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['multipleaccountsdetected']);
        }
    }


    if ($settings['multi_country'] == "yes") {
        if ($country != $user_info['country'] && $country != "-") {
            serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['multiplecountrydetected']);
        }
    }


    if ($user_info['status'] == "Un-verified") {
        serveranswer(0, $lang['txt']['accountinactive']);
    }
    else {
        if ($user_info['status'] == "Suspended") {
        serveranswer(0, "<strong>Your Account has been Suspended</strong>" . "<br />" . "<div class=\"site_content\"><div class=\"info_box\"><strong>Reason of Suspend</strong>" . "<br />" . $user_info['susreason']);
        }
    }
```

This code last line is the (if) statement when a user suspended then when system will do.

Comment: You say that a user must be logged in to show the suspending reason. But this means that your users table can be accessed only if a user is logged in. I think that you can read from it even without user data inside session, don't you?

Comment: `$user_info` does not come from the session - just from a database lookup on the username. Do some debugging to see why this not appearing for you.

Comment: @Giorgio i am not saying as you are talking that user must be logged in to show the suspending reason i am saying that my script show the suspend error to user even user did not logged in that's why it did not show the value of "susreason" column to suspended user.

Comment: this reason i have write when i suspend a user i have write some thing like a reason and this value subminted to the member column "susreason" but the script did not show this value to suspended user when he try to login . script only show the suspended and ($user_info['susreason']) this will not work because user are not logged in this field show blank .

Comment: @halfer you are right but i am not much expert in php i dont have any idea that how to debug i am trying to make some changes in the below codes and after that its show me susreason 0 .

Comment: $susreason = $db->fetchOne(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM members WHERE type='susreason'"));

Answer (score 0):

There are some security concerns with this code, so though this is not a direct answer to the question, I am writing them out as an answer, as they are important.

- Passwords hashed with MD5. This has not been an acceptable hashing algorithm for some years, because it is too fast and is prone to brute-force searching.
- No hash salting. This makes your passwords susceptible to look up with rainbow tables.

You should use `password_hash()` instead, which will solve both problems. This uses a slow algorithm (Bcrypt currently) that will increase in slowness as new PHP releases are made (to compensate for general increases in CPU performance, making it harder to brute-force attempt large numbers of passwords). It will also generate and store a salt as part of the hash output.

It looks like a user needs to get their username and password right before being told of a suspension reason. That is good - in most cases you don't want people to determine someone's suspension reason if they are just in possession of a username (which is usually public information).

Comment: your answer is totally against my question . i did not get you that what are you talking about .

Comment: What did you not understand, @JackVale? You have some security problems, and it is good for you to know what they are.

Comment: My Dear @halfer i just want to show the suspend reason to the suspended user and i have already put the reason when the time to suspend the user and this reason value saved in the table (members) at column (susreason) i want to show this column value to user at loging time when my script show error to user that you are suspended.

Comment: for further details you can read my other comments that i have submit in my question side .